# Difference between Naming and Registry in RMI

Tags: java, registry, rmi

I have used

```
Naming.rebind("rmi://localhost:1099/RmiServer", c);
```

where c is a remote object. And

```
 XYZ robj=new XYZ();
 ABC stub = (ABC) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(robj, 0);
 Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
 registry.bind("RmiServer", stub);
```

where stub is the remote object.

The first case is working fine if the rmiregistry is running already,but the later is throwing `ServerException that ClassNotFoundException` is thrown for ABC class. Where am i going wrong?

Also how are `Naming and Registry different` in the sense that here Naming is binding to local host whereas later is getting the corresponding port and address dynamically and then binding the object to it.

Comment: Looking at the source code (jdk 1.7.02), `Naming.rebind` calls `LocateRegistry.getRegistry(host, port)` and then invokes `rebind(name, obj)` on the result.  So, at the code level, there doesn't appear to be much difference. Can you post a short code example that illustrates your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The first case is working fine if the rmiregistry is running
>   already,but the later is throwing ServerException that
>   ClassNotFoundException is thrown for ABC class. Where am i going
>   wrong?

You have that back to front. If you use the separate `rmiregistry` you will get `ClassNotFoundExceptions` if the remote interfaces and stubs etc aren't on the rmiregistry's CLASSPATH. If you start the Registry in-process via `LocateRegistry.createRegistry()` that cannot happen, otherwise the export would have failed prior to the `bind()`.

> Also how are Naming and Registry different in the sense that here
>   Naming is binding to local host whereas later is getting the
>   corresponding port and address dynamically and then binding the object
>   to it.

`Naming` provides a set of static methods that interface to the Registry without you having to call `LocateRegistry.getRegistry()`. The API is pretty similar but the name strings are different: they are URL-based.

With the `Naming` class, all name strings are RMI URLs, e.g. rmi://localhost:1099/. This is true of all methods: bind(), rebind(), unbind(), lookup(), and list().

With the `Registry` interface, all name strings are just strings, e.g. <server-name>.

So if you're using both classes in different parts of the code, you need to keep this straight to ensure interoperability. For example it is possible to use Naming-style URLs in the Registry interface, they are just treated as strings, but then the results of Naming.list() would be something like rmi://localhost:1099/rmi://localhost:1099/<server-name>. So don't do that.

In both cases the names you get back from list() are the same kinds of names you would have supplied to one of the other methods.